# Can you use LINQ or lambdas to perform matrix operations?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I know how to do this using for loops.  Is it possible to do something like this using LINQ or lambdas?

```
int[] a = { 10, 20, 30 };
int[] b = { 2, 4, 10 };
int[] c = a * b; //resulting array should be { 20, 80, 300 }
```

Comment: but why would you even want to use LINQ? What's wrong with a trusty 'for loop' that everyone can understand?

Comment: ...or just use a Matrix class library...

Comment: Funny enough, I [answered another question today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311710/how-do-i-sum-a-list-of-arrays#311863) which sums numbers in place in two sequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: The code below will work, but it's not as readable as using an explicit method. LINQ is great where it definitely *adds* to readability... but this isn't one of those cases.

This is a briefer version of CMS's answer - the extra `let` isn't required, and when you're just doing a projection it's simpler to just use dot notation:

```
int[] result = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length)
                         .Select(i => a[i] * b[i])
                         .ToArray();
```

An alternative is to use the form of Select which takes an index:

```
int[] result = a.Select((value, index) => value * b[index])
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: @Jon: surely you are not encouraging people to do it this way!

Answer (score 5):

Using the Zip function (new to .NET 4.0) details [here](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx):

```
int[] a = { 10, 20, 30 };
int[] b = { 2, 4, 10 };

int[] c = a.Zip(b, (a1, b1) => a1 * b1).ToArray();
```

Until .NET 4 comes out you can use the zip implementation from the link above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
int[] a = {10, 20, 30};
int[] b = {2, 4, 10};

if (a.Length == b.Length)
{
  int[] result = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length)
          let operation = a[i]*b[i]
        select operation).ToArray();
}
```

But I recommend you if you will work with matrices and more advanced mathematical topics to get a good Math library, like [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/) or search for a [Matrix class](http://www.google.com/search?q=Matrix+C%23+.NET) implementation, there are many out there...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in, but you can always write your own functions. The first one below is a simple extension method doing what you want. The second allows you to specify the function to apply:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 10, 20, 30 };
        int[] b = { 2, 4, 10 };
        int[] c = a.MatrixMultiply(b);
        int[] c2 = a.Zip(b, (p1, p2) => p1 * p2);
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static int[] MatrixMultiply(this int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        // TODO: Add guard conditions
        int[] c = new int[a.Length];
        for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
        {
            c[x] = a[x] * b[x];
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static R[] Zip<A, B, R>(this A[] a, B[] b, Func<A, B, R> func)
    {
        // TODO: Add guard conditions
        R[] result = new R[a.Length];
        for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
        {
            result[x] = func(a[x], b[x]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [MSDN article on the upcoming PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) (Parallel LINQ).  From the article, here is an example of using PLINQ to parallelize matrix multiplication:

```
void ParMatrixMult(int size, double[,] m1, double[,] m2, double[,] result)
{
  Parallel.For( 0, size, delegate(int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      result[i, j] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        result[i, j] += m1[i, k] * m2[k, j];
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It's using LINQ and a Lambda!  And as a bonus it's spread across processors.

Comment: Actually it uses the Task Parallel Library (TPL) and delegates (not Lambda).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple extension that works with matrices of any rank.

```
public static class TwodimensionalArrayExtensions
{
    public static int[][] MultiplyBy(this int[][] leftMatrix, int[][] rightMatrix)
    {
        if (leftMatrix[0].Length != rightMatrix.Length)
        {
            return null; // Matrices are of incompatible dimensions
        }

        return leftMatrix.Select( // goes through <leftMatrix matrix> row by row

                (leftMatrixRow, leftMatrixRowIndexThatIsNotUsed) =>

                    rightMatrix[0].Select( // goes through first row of <rightMatrix> cell by cell

                            (rightFirstRow, rightMatrixColumnIndex) =>

                                rightMatrix
                                    .Select(rightRow => rightRow[rightMatrixColumnIndex]) // selects column from <rightMatrix> for <rightMatrixColumnIndex>
                                    .Zip(leftMatrixRow, (rowCell, columnCell) => rowCell * columnCell) // does scalar product
                                    .Sum() // computes the sum of the products (rowCell * columnCell) sequence.
                        )
                        .ToArray() // the new cell within computed matrix
            )
            .ToArray(); // the computed matrix itself
    }
}
```

Here are some test values:

```
// Test1
int[][] A = { new[] { 1, 2, 3 } };
int[][] B = { new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2 }, new[] { 3 } };
int[][] result = A.MultiplyBy(B);
```

---

```
// Test2
int[][] A = { new[] { 1 }, new[] { 2 }, new[] { 3 } };
int[][] B = { new[] { 1, 2, 3 } };
int[][] result = A.MultiplyBy(B);
```

---

```
// Test3
int[][] A = new int[][] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 2, 2 }, new[] { 3, 1 } };
int[][] B = new int[][] { new[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new[] { 2, 3, 2 } };
int[][] result = A.MultiplyBy(B);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the right matrix is transposed beforehand, multiplication can be expressed more elegantly as follows.

```
int[][] Multiply(int[][] left, int[][] right) =>
    left.Select(lr => 
            right
                .Select(rr => 
                    lr.Zipped(rr, (l, r) => l * r).Sum())
                .ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```